# Menu bar is inside search bar

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, user-interface, react-native-navigation

I am building a ecommerce App using React-Native;
I was trying to add Drawer Navigation but there few errors[image1 with drawer inside the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt8J5.jpg)

As you can see in the image it is inside the search bar, I want it beside search bar And second error is It's open inside the search bar as shown in the image below[image2 with drawer opened inside the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA0PZ.jpg)

Expected Behavior :

I want Menu beside search bar on blue header and I want to hide Home name displaced beside Menu icon

My Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, View, TextInput, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Menu from './Menu';

class Headers extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#22e3dd'}}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 24,
            marginLeft: 50,
            margin: 10,
            padding: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
            <Menu />
          <StatusBar
            barstyle="dark-content"
            backgroundColor="#22e3dd"
            hidden={false}
            translucent={false}
          />
          <Feather name="search" size={20} />
          <TextInput style={{height: 40, margin: 9}} placeholder="Search..." />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default Headers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have your Menu component inside of your View with the white background, just take it outside and that would fix the button placement.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#22e3dd',flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Menu />
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 24,
            marginLeft: 50,
            margin: 10,
            padding: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
            
          <StatusBar
            barstyle="dark-content"
            backgroundColor="#22e3dd"
            hidden={false}
            translucent={false}
          />
          <Feather name="search" size={20} />
          <TextInput style={{height: 40, margin: 9}} placeholder="Search..." />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked; I didnt notice flexdirection: row 
thanks alot i was stuck for 12hrs, you saved me.

Comment: Glad i could help ^^, what about opening and closing the menu is it working as expected?

Comment: no its still opening inside the header and i dont why but component (Home is being displayed beside the menu icon i just want menu icon on the header)

Comment: I think that the menu component shouldn't be inside of the header, you should only have a simple button in the header with a callback to trigger the opening of the menu